# How to include MPEG codec?

Tags: html, c++, css, ffmpeg, codec

Why embed video streams are not visible in my c++ program? I added WebBrowser into the program and the page that Browser should show is embed video stream. When I compile and run program, and when I press connect (button that should load web browser) it just loads black screen. That's when I use just embed video stream (valid one), when I use whole site where stream is, program loads whole site, expect stream which is black. What might be problem?

I tagged html and css in this post since they might know something about it too.

```
void__fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    UnicodeString code, key;
    int br;

    code = Edit1->Text;

    if (code=="C577F") br=1;
    if (code=="A9967") br=2;
    if (code=="G02C1") br=3;
    if (code=="TB4FA") br=4;
    if (code=="U3E4B") br=5;
    if (code=="KR11V") br=6;
    if (code=="DFF9D") br=7;
    if (code=="L738D") br=8;
    if (code=="AA46C") br=9;
    if (code=="EC6E7") br=10;
    if (code=="T7BCE") br=11;
    if (code=="JT429") br=12;
    if (code=="R5F2C") br=13;
    if (code=="O582B") br=14;
    if (code=="A1FB4") br=15;

    switch(br)
    {
        case 1:
            WebBrowser1->URL = "https://live-sports-stream.net/embed/video.php?channel=1";
            break;
        case 2:
            WebBrowser1->URL = "https://live-sports-stream.net/embed/video.php?channel=2";
            break;
        case 3:
            key="3";
            WebBrowser1->URL = "https://live-sports-stream.net/embed/video.php?channel=3";
            break;
        case 4:
            key="4";
            WebBrowser1->URL = "https://live-sports-stream.net/embed/video.php?channel=4";
            break;
        case 5:
            key="5";
            WebBrowser1->URL = "https://live-sports-stream.net/embed/video.php?channel=5";
            break;
        case 6:
            key="6";
            WebBrowser1->URL = "https://live-sports-stream.net/embed/video.php?channel=6";
            break;
        case 7:
            key="7";
            WebBrowser1->URL = "https://live-sports-stream.net/embed/video.php?channel=7";
            break;
        case 8:
            key="8";
            WebBrowser1->URL = "https://live-sports-stream.net/embed/video.php?channel=8";
            break;
        case 9:
            key="9";
            WebBrowser1->URL = "https://live-sports-stream.net/embed/video.php?channel=9";
            break;
        case 10:
            key="10";
            WebBrowser1->URL = "https://live-sports-stream.net/embed/video.php?channel=10";
            break;
        case 11:
            key="11";
            WebBrowser1->URL = "https://live-sports-stream.net/embed/video.php?channel=11";
            break;
        case 12:
            key="12";
            WebBrowser1->URL = "https://live-sports-stream.net/embed/video.php?channel=12";
            break;
        case 13:
            key="13";
            WebBrowser1->URL = "https://live-sports-stream.net/embed/video.php?channel=13";
            break;
        case 14:
            key="14";
            WebBrowser1->URL = "https://live-sports-stream.net/embed/video.php?channel=14";
            break;
        case 15:
            key="15";
            WebBrowser1->URL = "https://live-sports-stream.net/embed/video.php?channel=15";
            break;
        default:
            ShowMessage("Code not valid. Contact @account on instagram for a new one.");

    }
}
```

Comment: can anybody help?